# The usage of pronoun "so" and "that"

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between "I don't hope so." and "I don't hope that."?

Answer (score 2):

In today's english, when one says "I don't hope so", the speaker usually stops speaking. Whereas when one says "I don't hope that...", something is usually said that the speaker does not want to happen.

Comment: I can't imagine someone saying "I don't hope so" in the first place. You could say "I hope so" but the negation is usually expressed differently.

Comment: The usual negation is: _I hope not!_

Comment: To my ear (AmE), the phrase "I don't hope that" puts the emphasis on the *hoping* act, not the negation of whatever the hoper is hoping.  For example:  "You hope the Dodgers win; I don't hope that."

Comment: @Antimony: though "I don't hope so" is not used much in today's English, it is grammatically correct in spoken English.

Comment: @jbeldock: When you say "You hope the Dodgers win; I don't hope that.", you are saying that you do not want the Dodgers to win - this is the thing that you do not want to happen.